# Photogenic Places Between Williamsburg, Virginia and Roanoke, Virginia along I64

Tags: usa, sightseeing, transportation, photography

I'm planning on making this trip in a few weeks and I'm looking for nice places to stop that is slightly off of I64 to snap a few pictures. Using OnTheWay, I'm planning on stopping at Lake Monticello; I was just wondering if anybody here had any suggestions from their own experiences.

Specifics I'm interested in:

- Landscapes
- Natural places
- Giant balls of yarn (if Virginia has these)

Comment: Hi goldenfib and welcome to travel.SE.  The question you are asking is a bit too broad for the forum and can't be specifically answered because everyone's likes and dislikes are different.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't too sure how helpful (or active) this stackexchange is. I didn't think it would hurt. I'll delete this question in a few days if nobody responds.

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed much before that because it can't be definitively answered.  If you are looking for something specific you should clarify.

Comment: Okay, I didn't realize this question would be so poorly accepted; perhaps I'll delete it sooner if more people share your views.

Comment: Could you maybe be more specific? Do you want just natural things (lakes) or are you into, I dunno, giant balls of yarn, or windmills, or truck stops, or farm barns, or animals, or ....as you can see, @Karlson has a point, it's quite broad at present.  If you could update your question with a few more details, someone may be able to help :)

Comment: Thanks @MarkMayo. I tried to update my question, should I be much more specific?

Comment: that looks fine, lol @ the ball of yarn btw ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few places that claim to have the biggest or heaviest balls of yarn, but none of them are in VA:

- Darwin, Minnesota is the home of a [ball by Francis A. Johnson](http://www.roadsideamerica.com/story/2128). It is 4 meters (12 ft) in diameter and weighs 4,900 kg (10,400 lbs)
- Cawker City, Kansas. As of 2006, [the twine ball](http://kansastravel.org/balloftwine.htm) has reached nearly 9 tons! This is now the world's largest and heaviest ball of sisal twine.
- Lake Nebagamon, Wisconsin - [the ball weighs 19,336 pounds](http://destinationweird.wordpress.com/2010/09/19/worlds-heaviest-ball-of-twine-lake-nebagamon-wi/) (8,770 kg), making it the heaviest ball of twine ever built. The ball is housed in an open-air enclosure in James Frank Kotera's lawn. It's mass will eventually cause the Earth to gravitate towards the sun, destroying the planet.
- Branson, Missouri claims the title of having of [largest ball of twine](http://onlineschoolsmissouri.com/obscure-facts-about-missouri/) in the world. It measures a whopping 42 feet around, weighs over 6 tons, and is composed of 29 varieties of nylon string.

If that is to far away then take the turnoff at "Natural Bridge" from I64 where you can find Foamhenge, the most accurate Styrofoam replica of Stonehenge. Ranked [#2/8 on tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g58003-d610843-Reviews-Foamhenge-Natural_Bridge_Virginia.html) of all attractions in town.

Edit: According to the tripadvisor reviews, Foamhenge was moved to Fairfax County, VA in late 2016.